# Layout Issue of vue-select in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vue-select

When I test vue-select in POC project, it works well, see screen shot below:
[image]

However, when I use vue-select in my real project, it is disordered, see screen below, did any one have similar issue and how to fix it?

[image]

after @import "vue-select/src/scss/vue-select.scss";
[image]

Thanks
George

Answer (score 0):

You of course realize that no CSS is applied to the markup, so you need to apply some cuatom CSS.

Or, see the [Vue Select docs](https://vue-select.org/guide/install.html#yarn-npm)
how to include their default CSS:

> The component itself does not include any CSS. You'll need to include it separately:

```js
import 'vue-select/dist/vue-select.css';
```

> Alternatively, you can import the scss for complete control of the component styles:

```js
@import "vue-select/src/scss/vue-select.scss";
```

Comment: Thanks Shaya. I definitely included " import 'vue-select/dist/vue-select.css';" but it doesn't work. However I like to try with @import "vue-select/src/scss/vue-select.scss"; how to use it. Do I need to create a separate scss file under assets folder?   Thanks George

Comment: Hi Shaya, My existing project has css already, Can I have both css and scss?

Comment: @user1456650, in which file did you include `import 'vue-select/dist/vue-select.css';`?

Comment: Hi Shaya, I include import "vue-select/dist/vue-select.css" in nain.js

Comment: I did the same thing as that in POC project, POC works well.

Comment: after @import "vue-select/src/scss/vue-select.scss"; it is improved, but still not good, see 3rd screen shot above.

Comment: The clear button "X" and Arrow "^" are in spinning. in vue-select.scss, it imports:

Comment: it has imports "modules/spinner";  "global/animations"; I try to remove them, it doesn't work either